# Google Sheets! Issue with Image() Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Let me try to explain my issue.

1. I've an image in my Drive URL = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Qr0kRr6yOOLXB1OE5lUUxBRjQ"
2. I converted it to "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7Qr0kRr6yOOLXB1OE5lUUxBRjQ"

> > Replaced "open?id" with "uc?export=download&id"

3. I've modified URL of step 2 above  in Sheet1!A1

At Sheet1!A5 When I use =Image(A1,1) it doesn't works.

but when I use =Image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7Qr0kRr6yOOLXB1OE5lUUxBRjQ",2) it works. This shows up image.

Q: What's the reason that when i use direct URL with Image Function it works but when i give cell reference of containing URL it won't.

Please help to find the issue! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use =Image(&A1,1)

this means "&" puts the value of A1 in the image formula and displays the image.